# jmeter how to produce large number of service reqest in a second like 100.000 req/per sec

Tags: web-services, jmeter, load, stress-testing

I have been doing load test for very long in my company but tps never passed 500 transaction per minute. I have more challenging problem right now.

**Problem:** 
My company will start a campaing and ask a questiong to it's customers and first correct answer will be rewarded. Analists expect 100.000 k request in a second at global maximum. (doesnt seem to me that realistic but this can be negotiable)

**Resources:**
Jmeter,
2 different service requests,
5 x slave with 8 gb ram,
80 mbps internet connection,
3.0 gigahertz
Master computer with same capabilities with slaves.

**Question:**
How to simulete this scenario, is it possible? What are the limitations. How should be the load model. Are there any alternative to do that?

Any comment is important..

Comment: you need to worry about max threads, max ports and max RAM. Specifics depend on other things, e.g. if each service request is close to 1 sec, you will need 25k threads per slave - depending on your machines, it may be possible, or not. If your requests are very fast, say 10ms, you may have just 2500 threads per slave - not that much. But then you may run out of ports (actually in both cases you may run out of ports) . But really, it's something you ned to test and find out. Nobody will have an answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Your load test always need to represent real usage of application by real users so first of all carefully implement your test scenario to mimic real human using a real browser with all its stuff like:

   - [cookies](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
   - [headers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
   - [embedded resources (proper handling of images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc.)](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses)
   - [cache](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
   - [think times](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)
   - etc.
2. Make sure your test is following [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html), i.e.:

   - being run in non-GUI mode
   - all listeners are disabled
   - [JVM settings are optimised for maximum performance](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/JVMTuning.html)
   - etc.
3. Once done you need to set up monitoring of your JMeter engines health metrics like CPU, RAM, Swap usage, Network and Disk IO, [JVM stats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), etc. in order to be able to see if there is a headroom to continue. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) is very handy as its results can be correlated with the Test Metrics.
4. Start your test from 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load until you reach the target throughput / your application under test dies / JMeter engine(s) run out of resources, whatever comes the first. Depending on the outcome you will either report success or defect or will need to request more hosts to use as JMeter engines / upgrade existing hardware.